# Fórmula compleja con PHP/MySqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy haciendo unos cálculos en mysqli que no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.
Tengo una tabla, que suma los puntos de cada equipo, perfecto, pero necesito hacer un cálculo adicional en la cual necesito ayuda.

**Mi problema es con la columna en negrilla marcada como SB**. Para calcularla se debe proceder de la siguiente manera:
1.- Cada valor a sumar es el de la columna SUM.
2.- Solo se suma el valor, cuando un equipo ganó, es decir tiene 1 punto.
3.- Sumamos la mitad de puntos, de aquellos con quienes entablamos.
4.- Si un equipo perdió, no se suma nada.

Ver la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo 1: El equipo RDO:
RDO perdió con PRC, suma 0 
RDO ganó a BRA, suma 2 de la columna SUM
RDO empató con ARG, suma 1/2 de 4.5 de la columna SUM
RDO ganó a Ven, suma 2 de la columna SUM
RDO ganó a Nic, suma 2 de la columna SUM
SB de RDO = 2+4.5/2+2+2 = 8.25

Todo esto lo hago en excel si problema, pero en php/mysqli, necesito ayuda.

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede resolver haciendo las operaciones con condicionales en función del valor del campo. He considerado el valor por defecto 0, de modo que como un equipo no juega contra el mismo, ese valor es 0 (no suma en el total).

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id VARCHAR(5),
  RDO DECIMAL(2,1),
  PRC DECIMAL(2,1),
  BRA DECIMAL(2,1),
  ARG DECIMAL(2,1),
  VEN DECIMAL(2,1),
  NIC DECIMAL(2,1),
  SUM DECIMAL(2,1)
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('RDO',0,0,1,0.5,1,1,3.5);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('PRC',1,0,0,0,0,0,1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *,
IF (RDO=1,2,IF(RDO=0.5,RDO*SUM,RDO)) 
+ IF (PRC=1,2,IF(PRC=0.5,PRC*SUM,PRC)) 
+ IF (BRA=1,2,IF(BRA=0.5,BRA*SUM,BRA)) 
+ IF (ARG=1,2,IF(ARG=0.5,ARG*SUM,ARG)) 
+ IF (VEN=1,2,IF(VEN=0.5,VEN*SUM,VEN)) 
+ IF (NIC=1,2,IF(NIC=0.5,NIC*SUM,NIC)) AS TOTAL
FROM test;

| id  | RDO | PRC | BRA | ARG | VEN | NIC | SUM | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | ----- |
| RDO | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0.5 | 1   | 1   | 3.5 | 7.75  |
| PRC | 1   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 2     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)